# What is the correct way of writing typeof(Xml) for C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, types

I'm making a dictionary that maps .NET types to Sql Server types. I am using [MSDN's "SQL Server Data Type Mappings" page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx) to show me what the correct conversions are. At the bottom of the table it says the .NET framework type is Xml, and so I wrote:

```
{typeof (Xml), "xml"}
```

as a key-value pair of the dictionary. But Resharper has Xml in red and says it cannot resolve the symbol. What's the correct statement for typeof(Xml)? This is what the rest of my dictionary looks like and it doesn't have any problems:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<Type, string> SqlServerMap = new Dictionary<Type, string>
{
    {typeof (Int64), "bigint"},
    {typeof (Boolean), "bit"},
    {typeof (Byte[]), "binary"},
    {typeof (Double), "float"},
    {typeof (Int32), "int"},
    {typeof (Decimal), "decimal"},
    {typeof (Single), "real"},
    {typeof (Int16), "smallint"},
    {typeof (DateTime), "date"},
    {typeof (TimeSpan), "time"},
    {typeof (String), "nvarchar"},
    {typeof (Guid), "uniqueidentifier"},
    {typeof (Byte), "tinyint"},
    {typeof (Xml), "xml"}
};
```

Comment: There isn't really a .Net type for `Xml`. You could use `string` perhaps but that would interfere with your dictionary. Having said that, what about `char`, `varchar` and `nchar`? They should also be in your list as `string` type.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. Hmm, how would a one to many mapping work? Also I'm only using this mapping to create columns, and entries in the column are generally short. I'm not really sure about the differences between the four.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TO make the mapping from .NET to SQL for XML it appears that you need to use the SqlXml type, as there is no direct Xml type.

Here is a detailed [implementation example from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/34e4kcbw(v=VS.100).aspx).

When it comes to mapping you can use something like XDocument etc if you want and then manually swap it to a SqlXml for persistence possibly?

Comment: Thanks, I think this will work. Another option is to consider the use cases of what I'm doing. I'm not sure it's really necessary to have this mapping, so if it doesn't seem worth it I could just ignore it altogether.